# How to deny access to .git folder with server.fs.deny

Tags: vite

I don't understand how to deny access to all elements in the `.git` folder, in particular to `.git/logs/HEAD` file.

I used the StackBliz to understand the `server.fs.deny` setting.

I created a new file `vite.config.js` and add the following code:

```js
import { defineConfig, searchForWorkspaceRoot } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    fs: {
      deny: [
        searchForWorkspaceRoot(process.cwd()),
        ".git",
        ".env"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

then I added an `.env` and `.git/logs/HEAD` file in the root.

And it worked like charm, and if I navigate to the /.env or /.git address I get the correct answer from the server:

```bash
403 Restricted
The request url "/home/projects/vitejs-vite-1gpml7/.git" is outside of Vite serving allow list.

- /home/projects/vitejs-vite-1gpml7

Refer to docs https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-fs-allow for configurations and more details.
```

So tried to add all the folders or a specific file in the `.git` folder in all this way but nothing worked

```js
import { defineConfig, searchForWorkspaceRoot } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    fs: {
      deny: [
        searchForWorkspaceRoot(process.cwd()),
        ".git",
        ".env",
        //no working config
        ".git/logs/HEAD",
        "/.git/logs/HEAD",
        ".git/**/**",
        "/.git/**/**",
        "./.git/**"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

My final goal is to deny the access to all the files and folders of .git or at least to the HEAD file that contains sensible data about the commits.

I share with you my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-1gpml7?file=main.js) session so it's easier to test.